# Finding a simple residue

Tags: complex-analysis

The residue at the $z=7$ for $$\frac{1}{(z-7)^{5}}$$

is $0$ since the residue = 
$$
\lim_{z \to 7} = \frac{1}{(5-1)!}\frac{d^{4}}{dz^{4}}(z-7)^{5}\frac{1}{(z-7)^{5}}
$$

$$
\lim_{z \to 7} = \frac{1}{(24)}\frac{d^{4}}{dz^{4}}1 =  0
$$

Comment: What's problem????????????